# experimental evidence of fusion

Tags: physics

It is known that in the sun the main reaction is the fusion process which consumes hydrogen and generates helium.

While this is conceivable by the mass-energy equation, did people have any experimental evidence for it in the lab?

Comment: Please google before asking here, Wikipedia has a helpful article titled [List of fusion experiments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fusion_experiments) going back to 1970-s. People fused a lot more more than just hydrogen into helium, by the way.

Comment: Are you asking about experimental evidence of any kind of fusion, or are you asking about experimental evidence related specifically to steps in the proposed [proton chain reaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proton%E2%80%93proton_chain_reaction), which could potentially lead to a much more interesting answer!

Comment: @Conifold - a list going back to only the 1960's has little to do with the understanding of nuclear reactions, including fusion, dating back to the early part of the 1900's. Even moreso given Hans Bethe's Nobel Prize predates many of the ones listed there. And, yes, nuclear physics experiments are the basis for Bethe's work.

Comment: @JonCuster The very first link in that article is fusion power, which has [history of research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusion_power#History_of_research) section going back to 1920-s. Bethe's work is described under 1930-s.